# The method 'onSelectNotifications' isn't defined using flutter local notification plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, local

in [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) 12.0.2

The **onSelectNotification** parameter is not anymore.
So what is the alternative of this. So that we can handle callback when we click on notification.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can `stream` the notification

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
...
// use this 
class MyNotifManager {
static final onNotifications = BehaviorSubject<String?>();
...

// then add the payload to your local notification
// exampel for  the foreground notif

  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) async {
        onNotifications.add(payload.payload); // add payload to the stream
  },
```

then to handle the callback:

```
Future<void> listenNotification() async =>
      MyNotifManager.onNotifications.stream.listen(onClickNotification);
```

and for your action after click

```
void onClickNotification(String? payload) {
  Navigator.push();
}
```

call the stream on your initState

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MyNotifManager.init();
    listenNotification();
  }
```

with this method, you will able to handle calback when click on notification.

Comment: this is for reference guide.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRy5dmts3X8&t=434s

Answer (score 0):

It has `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` callback when plugin initialize.

```
    _plugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) {
          // Click Notification Event Here
      },
    );
```

If you click notification when app is terminated,

```
    _plugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails().then((value) {
         // Click Notification Event Here
    });
```

Comment: Does this work better than the old version?  Coz honestly, the old version could never really be trusted... And it would trigger the ´onSelectNotification´ event many times, and stuff...

Comment: This code doesn't support at old version. In old version, plz use `onSelectNotification`. If you use new version of flutter_location_notification, you can use `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` when app state is foreground. if app is open by clicking notification when app state is terminated, you can use `getNotificationAppLaunchDetails` in app init() or wherever you want to use. I think it would be better than old version. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#notification-actions

Comment: Yes, I got that, and it was of great help thanks! I just wanted to hear your spontaneous comment on whether or not it works better after the update or not...